# ggplot multiple lines in python, output only contains the first line

Tags: python, ggplot2

I try to use ggplot to plot the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from ggplot import *
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
df['y'] = [1,6,7,2,3,6]
df['id'] = ['a','a','b','b','c','c']
```

I get the output

```
   x  y id
0  1  1  a
1  2  6  a
2  3  7  b
3  4  2  b
4  5  3  c
5  6  6  c
```

I wish to plot 3 segments with different colors distinguished by 'id'.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x='x',y='y',colour='id')) + geom_line()
```

The output contains only the first segment 'a'

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbiny.png)

What's the problem of my codes?

Comment: I solved it myself. ;) The problem is just the version of ggplot. I installed the bad version.